# SSRS Using 2 Parameters or Just 1 Separate Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, report

I am hoping someone can provide me some insight. I am creating a Report for staff and in the parameters I would like to set them up in a flexible way.

Example:
Parameter1 = StreetNumber:_____ and Parameter2 = StreetName:______
*This Parameter will cascade and show only available street names for that number.

The issue is I would like to have a 3rd parameter called Parcel #___________ in which the user can check the NULL box for streetnumber and streetname and just search by the 1 field instead. When I have attempted this I can get Parameter 1 and 2 cascading to work fine but then leaving those null and just searching by Parameter3 it wants a value for Parameter2.

This is my dataset query where clause to establish the parameters:

```
WHERE (NUMBER=@STREETNUMBER AND STREETNAME=@STREETNAME)
OR (@STREETNUMBER IS NULL AND @STREETNAME IS NULL AND SCHD=@PARCELNO)
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: A few things before I think about it more...  Are the parameter name spelled exactly the same as they are in the query, they are case sensitive.   What happens if you test the dataset query in SSMS or similar?

Comment: I should have shown more attention to detail. They are Capitalized as shown in the query and match identically. The query in SSMS fine and I can toggle the first 2 parameters as null and input the PARCELNO or vise versa and set PARCELNO to null and input STREETNUMBER and STREETNAME

Comment: what happens if you allow for blank values instead of NULL? It looks tidier as well without having to tick the box

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you are trying to populate parameter values from a query AND trying to allow 'Null'. That will only work if you have `Null` in your parameters dataset query.

Try UNIONing a null to the end of both your parameter dataset queries.

So if the query for StreetNumber looks like this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT StreetNumber FROM myTable
```

then just change it to this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT StreetNumber FROM myTable
UNION SELECT NULL
```

You will have to do this to both parameter dataset queries.
I've just tested this and it worked as expected.